# Move subfolders up in a level in windows [script]

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, tree, directory

I would like to ask you guys if you could know a way to move a sh*tload of folders up in my tree.

Basically, I have a main folder where it contains a lot of [subfolders](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AghHn03Y7t4gqgeP-PRUFnm39-Ej). Each of these either:

-Contains [subsubfolders themselves](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AghHn03Y7t4gqgjrspDSvTIDyNHN) (in which case I would like to take these subsubfolders and put them in my main folder.

-Contains [only files and no folders inside](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AghHn03Y7t4gqglsX6WjtZMFxNIn) (in which case I would like to not touch them).

Could this be possible to write a batch file or any script that moves the one needed while not touching the ones without folders?

Comment: Any special request with being batch? Would python work for you?

Comment: Of course! As long as it works.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues - What does python have to do with batch files? We're not talking about batch processing; the tag is meant for the windows command prompt.